# fastText -autotune-validation not working

Tags: fasttext

I am trying to use the autotune-validation command to check the f1 score of a dataset I am working in.

I tested fastText in two different machines (Ubuntu and MAC), but I got the following error:

```
Unknown argument: -autotune-validation

The following arguments are mandatory:
  -input              training file path
  -output             output file path

The following arguments are optional:
  -verbose            verbosity level [2]

...
```

I tried to read the documentation, but according to the fastText website, this command should work fine.

```py
./fasttext supervised -input commits.train -output commits -autotune-validation commits.valid
```

I expected the -autotune-validation command to work fine as described [here](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/autotune.html)

Comment: Maybe you're not using the latest version...

Comment: Yup, I wasn't in the latest version indeed, the pip version of fastText installation is still bringing an old version of the package. When I built it from GitHub it worked just fine