# FastText autotune error while running it in the command line

Tags: fasttext

I am using fastText0.9.1, each time I try to `run ./fasttext supervised -input cooking.train -output model_cooking -autotune-validation cooking.valid`, but I get this error:
`Unknown argument: -autotune-validation`
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please edit your question to include in it any code you have already tried. Consider the guidelines on how to best ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Please read this issue: https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/889
and also this answer: [fastText -autotune-validation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58598754/fasttext-autotune-validation-not-working)

Maybe you are using an old version of fastText.